# How to change the driving side in GTA 4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Is it possible to change the driving side in GTA-4? In the game you drive on the right side, but in my country, India, we drive on the left side of the road.

And in the game it becomes a lot harder to chase or win the races for me, as I tend to drive on the left side of the road.

Is it possible to change the driving side in the game? Is there any cheat that will do this?

Comment: Funny, I never had problems playing GTA: London many years ago :)

Comment: Maybe you can just flip the video and controls left to right. It will make text harder to read, though

Comment: I don't know about GTA 4, but I've never had a problem driving on the right side of the road in any of the GTA games. I've also had very few problems driving on the sidewalks, medians, parks, train tracks... deep water tends to be a problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking this is almost impossible to do, because I think I read somewhere that the way the cars go from A to B is hardcoded in the game, meaning it would take a lot of skill, and heavily modifying the game to actually do. I can't find the source for it though ... I'll try looking for it later on.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way.

However, now you know how everyone in the U.S. felt playing Sleeping Dogs.